# Booting EFI on KVM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, uefi

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 running kernel 3.19. I'm trying to use virt-manager to start a virtual machine. I have installed `ovmf` for EFI firmware and booted the machine with a Gentoo ISO in the CD slot.

I see the OVMF firmware logo, then some log messages like this:

```
Boot failed. EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot failed. EFI Floppy.
Boot failed. EFI Floppy 1.
```

It then initializes the network card, presumably for network boot, and then drops to an EFI shell:

[image]

How do I get EFI booting working in KVM/libvirt?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this recently. If you type exit followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> it drops you in a menu where you can change boot order or add new boot devices. It also helps to have bootable media, like a disk image or iso, attached to the VM.

Comment: You can also use this menu to turn off secure boot, which might get things working if you're not using a signed boot loader.